# How to define a post category undeletable by other users?

Tags: categories

I would define a post category and I would make it not editable e not deletable by other users? Is it possible in some way?

Comment: yes possible set role for user

Comment: try this plugins : https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/

Comment: you mean just one category shall be un-editable and un-deleteable, not all?